# Reformatting dataframe for ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a multiple bars plot but I am struggling to reformat my data for ggplot.

my data looks like this now in R, in a data frame:

```
                 var1     var2     var3

       Sample1    2        3       4

       Sample2    4        45      67
```

I need this format:

```
Sample1   var1  2
Sample1   var2  3
Sample1   var3  4
Sample2   var1  4
Sample2   var2  45
Sample2   var3  67
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Yes, many thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use tidyr and pivot_longer.

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(var1:var3, names_to = 'Names', values_to = 'Values')
```